# How to match IP host from Rust URL?

Tags: url, rust

I'm trying to get the IPv4 from the URL below:

```
use url::{Url, Host};
use std::net::{SocketAddr, IpAddr};

fn main () {
    let url = Url::parse("rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.178:10554/tcp/av0_0").unwrap();
    let port = url.port().unwrap_or(554);
    let ip_address = match url.host() {
        Some(Host::Ipv4(ipv4)) => SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V4(ipv4), port),
        Some(Host::Ipv6(ipv6)) =>  SocketAddr::new(IpAddr::V6(ipv6), port),
        None => panic!("missing host"),
        _ => panic!(format!("only IP hosts are accepted. Your host: {:?}", url.host()))
    };
    println!("{}", ip_address);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4dcca5fecf0bb1a8688b3de773bb1093)

but it panics:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'only IP hosts are accepted. Your host: Some(Domain("192.168.1.178"))', src/main.rs:11:14
```

What is wrong? The host is clearly an ip address.

Comment: From the docs it looks like both of them take a list of numbers? `Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: @Dominic I did not understand. I'm parsing a string url

Comment: It's to do with the `rtsp` scheme. If you change it to `http` it works.

Comment: Digging into the parsing code, http, https, ws, wss, and ftp schemes are parsed "special" and rtsp is not. Not sure why this has the effect you're observing. https://docs.rs/url/2.2.1/src/url/parser.rs.html#470

Comment: @Schwern because [URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/), the URL Standard has [special schemes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme) and differentiates the host semantics based on those: [special schemes can have a Domain, IPv4 or IPv6 host while non-special schemes have an Opaque Host or IPv6 host](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-representation). And `url` apparently uses `Domain` for opaque hosts. And after testing I can confirm that ipv6 addresses are in fact recognized for rtsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking a the bug tracker, I found [IP is not recognized in RTSP url](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/issues/606).

The answer is apparently that `url` follows / implements the URL Standard (which makes sense as it was developed in the context of Servo), and the URL Standard only requires IP**v4** address recognition of a select number of schemes because those schemes (apparently) handle IPv4 addresses specially: https://github.com/servo/rust-url/issues/577

Specifically: [the special schemes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme) are ftp, http, https, ws, wss (there's also `file` but it's its own category), and the differences in [host representation](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-representation) are that:

- a special scheme's host can be ipv4, ipv6, or domain
- a non-special scheme's host can be ipv6, opaque, empty, or null

`url` will in fact parse ipv6 for non-special schemes, though everything else it just dumps into `Some(Domain(...))` (or `None`).

Anyway this means that if you get a `Domain` result, you probably want to try and parse it as an IP.

Incidentally, you don't have to `format!` to format your panic messages, `panic!` will do that internally.